# Master Slave Synchronization with database

Tags: java, database, operating-system, distributed-computing, master-slave

This is just a  simple thought which came to my mind. I read at many places about the synchronizing databases in distributed architecture. I wanted to know and understand why master slave model in distributed systems will not work for synchronizing databases between different clients. Any ideas or suggestions are welcome. I am pretty new to distributed world.